# Merging three tables with one Primary Key and the result of each table should be displayed one by one

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have three tables, and they have one common field. I want to select all the rows of each table, ordered by that common field, and the result should be as the 1st row is from 1st table, the 2nd row is from 2nd table, and the 3rd row is from 3rd table.

What query would work for the above task? Have given the sample data of three tables and the required output as below. kindly excuse me if my question is clumsy !!

```
TABLE1      
WO      STATUS      SITE
1001    Released    36
1002    Closed      31
1003    Released    42

TABLE2          
WO  LINE NO   PRICE     QTY
1001    1     100        2
1001    2     300        3
1002    1     1500       3
1003    1     100        4
1003    2     200        2
1003    3     100        1

TABLE3      
WO      USER    SIGN ID
1001    Chrish  CRS
1001    Jovan   JVN
1002    Roopesh ROO
1003    Brian   BRN
1003    Suren   SRN
1003    Pavith  PAV
```

and the output should be like

```
RESULT              
TABLE1  1001    Released    36  
TABLE2  1001    1   100     2
TABLE2  1001    2   300     3
TABLE3  1001    Chrish      CRS 
TABLE3  1001    Jovan       JVN 
TABLE1  1002    Closed      31  
TABLE2  1002    1   1500    3
TABLE3  1002    Roopesh     ROO 
TABLE1  1003    Released    42  
TABLE2  1003    1   100     4
TABLE2  1003    2   200     2
TABLE2  1003    3   100     1
TABLE3  1003    Brian       BRN 
TABLE3  1003    Suren       SRN 
TABLE3  1003    Pavith      PAV
```

Comment: mysql or oracle? Choose one. Show us your db schema, sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks..have edited !!

Comment: much better, but your result format is weird looks like you have more data than columns.

Comment: Is this possible bro ??

Comment: You realize the data are trying to join doesnt have same type?

Comment: Yes !! they are not of same type !! will a Pivot do this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/PDIX79985)**

```
SELECT 'T1' as source, "WO", "STATUS" as f2, CAST("SITE" AS text)  as f3, null as f4
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT 'T2' as source, "WO", CAST("LINE NO" AS text) as f2, CAST("PRICE" AS text) as f3, "QTY" as f4
FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT 'T3' as source, "WO", "USER" as f2,  "SIGN ID" as f3, null as f4
FROM Table3 
ORDER BY "WO", source
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
select commonfield, fld1, fld2 from (
    select commonfield, uniquefield1 as fld1, uniquefield2 as fld2, 1 as sort from table1
    union
    select commonfield, uniquefield1, uniquefield2, 2 as sort from table2
    union
    select commonfield, uniquefield1, uniquefield2, 3 as sort from table3
) as qry
order by qry.commonfield, qry.sort
```

Comment: Thanks buddy !! But table 2 and and table 3 has other columns to display !! I need those columns too.

Comment: Edited to show adding some unique fields. uniquefield1 can be a different field name from all 3 tables, but the value from each table will be displayed in the same column, named fld1 / fld2 as defined in the first qry in your union.

Comment: Buddy !! i have edited my question and added some sample data for your kind reference !